# Safari Power Saver hides facebook games, any way around it?

Tags: facebook, flash, safari

**Problem:** (Sometimes) our games show up as nothing but a blank screen where the flash content is supposed to show. This leads users to believe the flash is not loading at all, and it takes seconds of hovering on top of the flash before the "Click to start Flash Plug-in" shows up.

From apple:

"*The new Safari Power Saver feature recognizes the difference between what you came to see and the stuff you probably didn’t. **If the content is front and center it plays as usual**. But if it’s off in the margins, Safari Power Saver pauses it. **You’ll see a static preview**, and it won’t run until you click to play it.*" /http://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/

**If the content is front and center it plays as usual** - I'd say a game on facebook is pretty front and center but it's still hidden.

**You’ll see a static preview** - not for us, it's just white.

I assume there is no way to disable Power Saver for the user since that would defeat it's purpose, but **is there a way to at least let Safari know what preview to show?**

Comment: Which game are you trying to run, and what platform are you trying to run it on?

Comment: I'd rather not say which game, but it's quite common for flash based facebook games, most notable example being https://apps.facebook.com/candycrush/ but also for example https://apps.facebook.com/lost-bubble/ and more. Not seen so far on any of the few Zynga games I've tried. I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.5 on a 2012 MBP. Safari 6.1.